# Making an interactive BulletGauge

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

For the purposes of an interactive demonstration I need to use a bullet gauge to readily show a moment in which the manipulated parameter passes a certain point. Like this, where the point Lambda=0.5 must be highlighted:

```
    Manipulate[
 col = If[\[Lambda] < 0.5, Red, Blue];
 Plot[Sin[\[Lambda]*x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]} ],
 Column[{
   Control[{{\[Lambda], 0.5, 
      Dynamic@Panel[
        Row[{Style["\[Lambda]=", col, 14, Italic], 
          Style[NumberForm[\[Lambda], {3, 2}], col, 14, Italic]}], 
        ImageSize -> {70, 40}]}, 0.3, 0.7}],
   Row[{Spacer[65], 
     Dynamic[BulletGauge[{\[Lambda]}, {0.5}, {0.3, 0.7}, 
       GaugeStyle -> col, ImageSize -> {200, 60}]]}]

   }], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

That works fine. What I do not like here is the excess of the elements. Indeed, there are both the slider and the bullet gauge. It is too much. It scatters the attention.

**My question**: Do you know a way to make the BulletGauge interactive, such that it could be picked up by the mouse (say, by the edge of the blue/red stripe) and moved like a slider?

If that were possible I would like to make a demonstration with only such an interactive BulletGauge but without any Slider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EventHandler` to capture mouse clicks in the graphic of the `BulletGauge`. You need to rescale the mouse coordinates to make it work, but this should give you a decent start in the right direction:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 50, max = 100, update},
 update[] := (x = max * First[MousePosition["Graphics"]]);
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[BulletGauge[x, 80, {0, max}]],
  {
   "MouseClicked" :> update[],
   "MouseDragged" :> update[]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

*edit*

At the OP's request, here's a minimal example of the bullet gauge as a control for a plot. Note that I'm not using `Manipulate`: in cases like these, it's usually easier to code up your own `Dynamic`s and controls inside of a `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{
  \[Lambda] = 0.5, 
  col,
  \[Lambda]min = 0.3,
  \[Lambda]max = 0.7,
  update
},
 col[x_] := If[x < 0.5, Red, Blue];
 update[] := (\[Lambda] = \[Lambda]min + (\[Lambda]max - \[Lambda]min)*First[MousePosition["Graphics"]]);
 Column[
  {
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[
     BulletGauge[\[Lambda], {0.5}, {\[Lambda]min, \[Lambda]max}, 
      GaugeStyle -> col[\[Lambda]]
     ]
    ], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> update[], "MouseDragged" :> update[]}
   ],

   Dynamic[Plot[Sin[\[Lambda]*x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]

   }
  ],
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

Comment: Could you please integrate your construct with the plot. I did not succeed.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need.